# unable to resolve dependency tree - ERESOLVE

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dependencies

I am trying to run an old project on my new system but while doing `npm install`,  this is what I am getting..

[image]

I've tried using same `Node` and `NPM` versions as per my old system, but nothing worked for me..

here is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "6.0.3",
"@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "6.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "12.2.16",
"@angular/cdk": "12.2.13",
"@angular/common": "12.2.16",
"@angular/compiler": "12.2.16",
"@angular/core": "12.2.16",
"@angular/forms": "12.2.16",
"@angular/material": "12.2.13",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "12.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.16",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.16",
"@angular/router": "12.2.16",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/core": "5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.11.0",
"@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.6",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
"@ng-idle/core": "11.1.0",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "11.0.3",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "7.4.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "12.1.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "5.0.0",
"angular-email-editor": "^0.9.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
"browserslist": "^4.20.2",
"chart.js": "^3.5.1",
"command": "0.0.5",
"core-js": "3.8.3",
"cronstrue": "^2.2.0",
"file-saver-es": "^2.0.5",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"moment": "^2.29.3",
"ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
"ng2-ckeditor": "1.3.6",
"ngx-doc-viewer": "^2.1.2",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
"ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
"primeicons": "^5.0.0",
"primeng": "^12.2.2",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"validator": "^13.7.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"


 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.16",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/file-saver-es": "2.0.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "~17.0.23",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "ini": "^1.3.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  }
```

I've tried resolving dependencies using following command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

And also this..

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

but ended up getting more dependencies errors, Also tried to clear cache and did a fresh install

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

but nothing is working. stuck on this error since yesterday, and it is getting on my nerves now.. Any kind of help will be much much appreciated.

PS: I know these kind of questions have already been asked here, but nothing worked for me.. tried each and every solution that worked for someone, but bad luck for me as of now..

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you, but this error most likely has to do with your node version and npm version not being compatible. I think you should check again and maybe try a few different node versions. You could try that with NVM: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: I did try with different node versions... but it didn't work for me...

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules folder and package-lock.json, then reinstalling again using the legacy-peer-deps flag?

Comment: yup, I did try each and everything I could possibly do...